# High Current Inductor Switching

Tags: switches, ac, inductor, passive-networks

I am looking for some suggestions on how to handle switching between two, hi-power LC circuits that provide an AC drive source for dynamic loads.  The LC target frequencies are ~1MHz for one application and ~2MHz for the other, but both are driving loads of up to 10A.  The existing setup requires two different circuits depending on the load and I'm trying to figure out how they could be combined into a single circuit that could drive either load.  The catch is that I need to do this without having to physically swap boards or components.

Anyone have any suggestions on where to start or general advice?

[image]

Comment: There is no C1 and C2, it's only one C=C1+C2. Is it okay for your application?

Comment: @Celdtun How about having one inductor and a switched capacitor? Maybe that's not possible?

Comment: MOSFETs could be used to switch the driver between the two inductors

Comment: @Janka: You are correct, I will have to independently control the Caps or make the combined capacitance the target value.

Comment: @Andy aka: Good suggestion and something I plan to explore

Comment: @ EE_social: this would be an ideal solution, however I'm going to focus on switching the caps since that will only require a N-FETs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the replies.

Doing a some calculations, I tweaked the values such that I could use a common inductor and MOSEFET controlled capacitors to achieve the desired output.  This will still need to be verified in the lab, but it looks like the best path going forward.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.